# URL link of Near Protocol block 1

Tags: cryptocurrency

Does anyone have a URL link or hash string where I can view the block 1 information of the cryptocurrency `Near Protocol`?

I'm working on a cryptocurrency related report. I would like to use it as evidence to prove when the Genesis block was created.
In the case of other cryptocurrencies, URLs based on block numbers exist and are easily obtained. However, `Near Protocol` seems to only have hash string-based URLs.
I can go back one block at a time on the [nearblocks.io](https://nearblocks.io/), but I think it would be impossible to go through all of the 110 million blocks currently created. Does anyone know the hash string?